# How to query result for pervious day

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark, I have a data frame which has a column 'Date' which is in 'Date and Time' for each row in the table.

I would like to query all the rows in the data frame which happened in previous day (i.e. the day before when I execute the query).

I see this doc https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/subtract-or-add-days-months-and-years-to-timestamp-in-pyspark/ which talks about how to create a column in data frame which subtracts a day from the values in a column.

But what I am looking for is now to subtract a day from current date and use that in filter.

Comment: you're looking for how to create the where clause. Nothing to do with pyspark. Get current date, substract one day, use it in where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kashyap comment says it all but here is an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
df.filter(col("Date") == yesterday).show()
```

If your Date column actually contains datetimes, you can truncate the datetimes to convert them into dates first.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_trunc
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
df.filter(date_trunc("day", col("Date")) == yesterday).show()
```

`date_trunc` will only work well with timestamp columns, not strings.

Make sure you replace `df` with your DataFrame name.

Comment: But in the table 'Date' has `Date And Time` , so I can't just do col("Date") == yesterday

Comment: Just put your column name in place of ```col("Date")``` like ```col("Date and Time")```

Comment: @n179911a I have included how to do it for date and time in my latest edit.